# How to retrieve all the child tags based on given parent tag using XML and Java?

Tags: java, xml, automation, xml-parsing

I have an XML file and I want to read all the child nodes / tags values for the given **Parent** tag.

**Sample XML content:**

```
<ns2:customerSummary>
               <ns2:address>
                  <ns2:city>SOUTH CHESTERFIELD</ns2:city>
                  <ns2:country>USA</ns2:country>
                  <ns2:isoCountryCode>US</ns2:isoCountryCode>
                  <ns2:line1>9998, N. MICHIGAN ROAD.</ns2:line1>
                  <ns2:postalCode>23834</ns2:postalCode>
                  <ns2:state>VA</ns2:state>
               </ns2:address>
               <ns2:allowPasswordChange>true</ns2:allowPasswordChange>
               <ns2:arpMember>false</ns2:arpMember>
               <ns2:brandCode>RCI</ns2:brandCode>
               <ns2:brandId>1</ns2:brandId>
               <ns2:companyCode>RCI</ns2:companyCode>
               <ns2:eliteMemberRewardStatus>false</ns2:eliteMemberRewardStatus>
               <ns2:eliteRewardStatus>true</ns2:eliteRewardStatus>
               <ns2:europePointsClubMember>false</ns2:europePointsClubMember>
               <ns2:firstName>FRANK</ns2:firstName>
               <ns2:homePhone>804/733-3004</ns2:homePhone>
               <ns2:isoCurrencyCode>USD</ns2:isoCurrencyCode>
               <ns2:isoLanguageCode>EN</ns2:isoLanguageCode>
               <ns2:language>EN</ns2:language>
               <ns2:lastName>BROWNING B</ns2:lastName>
               <ns2:locale>en_US</ns2:locale>
```

For example, if I provide the tag like **"ns2:customerSummary"** as parent tag it should return all the siblings / child nodes and their data Or if the parent tag is **"ns2:address"** it should return like city, country etc.

I have tried like this but, it takes from the top level.

```
public static void getAllChildTags(String strXmlFile, String strParentTag) {

    String strXmlFileName = System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + "\\resources\\customers.xml";
    String tagName = "ns2:customerSummary";

    // Parse Xml File
    parseXmlFile(strXmlFileName);

    //get the root element
    Element docEle = dom.getDocumentElement();

    Node childNode = docEle.getFirstChild();

    while (childNode.getNextSibling() != null)
    {
        childNode = childNode.getNextSibling();

        if (childNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
        {
            Element childElement = (Element) childNode;
            System.out.println("Node -> " + childElement.getNodeName() + " Value -> " + childElement.getNodeValue());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the logic and wrote the script for fetching all the child elements data based on the given parent tag. Look at this.

```
// This method returns all the child elements of the given Parent tag
public static void getAllChildTags(String strXmlFile, String strParentTag) {

    // Parse Xml File
    parseXmlFile(strXmlFile);

    NodeList flowList = dom.getElementsByTagName(strParentTag);

    for (int i = 0; i < flowList.getLength(); i++)
    {
        NodeList childList = flowList.item(i).getChildNodes();

        for (int j = 0; j < childList.getLength(); j++)
        {
            Node child = childList.item(j);
            if (!child.getNodeName().equals("#text"))
            {
                System.out.println(child.getNodeName() + " -> " + childList.item(j).getTextContent());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks,